# How to read a text file and write the content into another text file using stdio.h C library

Tags: c, file-io

I have written a function as follows to read a text file and write the content into another text file with a different file name:

**The read file function:**

```
char *getFileContent (const char *fileName)
{
char errorBuffer[50];

//Prepare read file
FILE *pReadFile;
long bufferReadSize;
char *bufferReadFile; //This variable is going to be returned as file content
size_t readFileSize;

pReadFile = fopen (fileName, "rb");

if (pReadFile != NULL)
{
    // Get file size.
    fseek (pReadFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    bufferReadSize = ftell (pReadFile);
    rewind (pReadFile);

    // Allocate RAM to contain the whole file:
    bufferReadFile = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * bufferReadSize);

    if (bufferReadFile != NULL) 
    {
        // Copy the file into the buffer:
        readFileSize = fread (bufferReadFile, sizeof(char), bufferReadSize, pReadFile);

        if (readFileSize == bufferReadSize) 
        {
            return bufferReadFile;

            fclose (pReadFile);
            free (bufferReadFile);
        } else {
            //fread failed              
            sprintf (errorBuffer, "File reading failed for file:\n%s", fileName);
            MessageBox (NULL, errorBuffer, "Error file reading", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        }
    } else {
        //malloc failed
        sprintf (errorBuffer, "Memory allocation failed for file:\n%s", fileName);
        MessageBox (NULL, errorBuffer, "Error memory allocation", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }       
} else {
    //fopen failed
    sprintf (errorBuffer, "File opening failed for file:\n%s", fileName);
    MessageBox (NULL, errorBuffer, "Error file opening", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
}
}
```

**The write file code:**

```
//Get file content from read file
char *fileContent = getFileContent (readFileName);
FILE *pWriteFile = fopen (writeFileName, "wb");
fwrite (fileContent, sizeof (char), strlen (fileContent), pWriteFile);
fclose (pWriteFile);
```

They successfully work together to read and write files. However, in the written file, at the end of it, some strange characters come out like this:

> ýýýý««««««««îþîþîþ

Please kindly help me solve this problem. How can I avoid the final strange characters in the written file when they were not there in the original file?

Comment: Just as a comment, in the read routine, the fclose and free never happen because they are after the return statement.

Comment: If this is a binary file, you can't use strlen() to determine the length of the data. You need to get the size of the data from the read routine.

Comment: What is the input file content? Can you show it to us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fwrite (fileContent, sizeof (char), strlen (fileContent), pWriteFile);
```

`strlen`() doesn't work here because fileContent contains binary data. The binary data could contain a null byte which would mean `strlen`() would be too short, or it may not contain a null byte which means `strlen`() would read past `fileContent` until it finds a null byte. This would be a reason why you see garbage at the end.

Note also, in your read routine, that the `fclose`() and the `free`() never happen because they come after the `return` statement. But, note that you can't `free`() the data until after you write it.

On the other hand, if it's not a binary file, all you need is a terminating 0 at the end of the data and then strlen() would work. So in your read, you need to alloc another byte and make sure that byte is zero:

```
bufferReadFile = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * bufferReadSize + 1); // note the + 1
bufferReadFile[bufferReadSize] = 0; // the terminating null byte.
```